# Gaps between columns are too wide in Latex (or Lyx)

Tags: tables, lyx, columns

I am writing up my dissertation and this particular table has bothered me for a while. I've tried many ways to shorten length, shrink the table (which I really want to avoid because I want to have consistency in my margins and font size).

Here is Latex code extracted from my Lyx file. I keep almost original code because my table is both long and wide (so I have to use `longtable` and `landscape` to make it work - if anyone know other way doing it, please let me know):

This is a picture of my resulted table. I want to shorten the gaps between each column. I feel they are quire redundant and my table is now going over the right margin.

I am looking to shorten the gaps to make my table fit within an A4 page neatly.

Thank you very much.

[image]

```
\documentclass[oneside,english]{mwbk}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{eulervm}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,lmargin=1in,rmargin=1in}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
\newcommand{\noun}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
%% Because html converters don't know tabularnewline
\providecommand{\tabularnewline}{\\}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[format=hang]{caption}

\AtBeginDocument{
  \def\labelitemi{\(\star\)}
  \def\labelitemii{\(\bullet\)}
}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
  \begin{landscape} 

\begin{longtable}{lcccc>{\centering}p{2.25cm}>{\centering}p{2.24cm}}
\caption{\textbf{\noun{This is my tables. }}}
\tabularnewline
\midrule
\multirow{2}{*}{\noun{Variables}} & \multicolumn{6}{c}{\noun{Name of dependent variables}}\tabularnewline
\cmidrule{2-7} 
 & (1)  & (2)  & (3)  & (4)  & (5)  & (6) \tabularnewline
\midrule
\emph{Measures of incentives} &  &  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
~~This is a long description that I can't shrink 201 & 0.10{*} (0.04)  &  &  & 0.07 (0.17)  &  & \tabularnewline
~~This is a long description that I can't shrink 201 &  & 0.00 (0.59)  &  &  & 0.00 (0.63)  & \tabularnewline
~~This is a long description that I can't shrink 2012 &  &  & 0.00 (0.11)  &  &  & 0.00 (0.20) \tabularnewline
~~This is a long description that I can't shrink 201 &  &  & 0.00 (0.92)  &  &  & 0.00 (0.85) \tabularnewline
~~This is a long description that I can't shrink 201 &  &  & 0.00 (0.60)  &  &  & 0.00 (0.45) \tabularnewline
\emph{Measures of private benefits} &  &  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
~~This is a long description that I can't shrink 201 & 0.28{*} (0.00)  & 0.24{*} (0.00)  & 0.23{*} (0.00)  & 0.29{*} (0.00)  & 0.25{*} (0.00)  & 0.25{*} (0.00) \tabularnewline
~~This is a long description that I can't shrink 201 & 0.34{*} (0.00)  & 0.35{*} (0.01)  & 0.37{*} (0.01)  & 0.36{*} (0.00)  & 0.40{*} (0.00)  & 0.41{*} (0.00) \tabularnewline
~~This is a long description that I can't shrink 201 & 0.09 (0.11)  & 0.14{*} (0.01)  & 0.12{*} (0.03)  & 0.08 (0.18)  & 0.13{*} (0.03)  & 0.11{*} (0.04) \tabularnewline
~~This is a long description that I can't shrink 201 & 0.14{*} (0.09)  & 0.15{*} (0.06)  & 0.15{*} (0.07)  & 0.13 (0.12)  & 0.15{*} (0.07)  & 0.14{*} (0.08) \tabularnewline
~~This is a long description that I can't shrink 201 & 0.00 (0.46)  & 0.00 (0.65)  & 0.00 (0.81)  & 0.00 (0.84)  & -0.00 (0.86)  & -0.00 (0.78) \tabularnewline
~~This is a long description that I can't shrink 201 & 0.01 (0.88)  & -0.10 (0.22)  & -0.12 (0.16)  & -0.01 (0.95)  & -0.12 (0.16)  & -0.13 (0.13) \tabularnewline
~~This is a long description that I can't shrink 201 & 0.23{*} (0.07)  & 0.33{*} (0.04)  & 0.34{*} (0.04)  & 0.17 (0.15)  & 0.29{*} (0.06)  & 0.29{*} (0.06) \tabularnewline
~~This is a long description that I can't shrink 201 & 0.03 (0.53)  & 0.04 (0.52)  & 0.02 (0.73)  & 0.02 (0.76)  & 0.00 (0.98)  & -0.01 (0.85) \tabularnewline
~~This is a long description that I can't shrink 201 & 0.09 (0.29)  & 0.08 (0.39)  & 0.07 (0.45)  & 0.06 (0.49)  & 0.03 (0.71)  & 0.03 (0.74) \tabularnewline
~~This is a long description that I can't shrink 201 & 0.09 (0.18)  & 0.10 (0.19)  & 0.06 (0.38)  & 0.02 (0.75)  & 0.03 (0.68)  & 0.00 (0.96) \tabularnewline
~~This is a long description that I can't shrink 201 & 0.09 (0.14)  & 0.12{*} (0.05)  & 0.10{*} (0.10)  & 0.07 (0.28)  & 0.07 (0.23)  & 0.06 (0.30) \tabularnewline
~~This is a long description that I can't shrink 201 & 0.06 (0.20)  & 0.07 (0.16)  & 0.06 (0.24)  & 0.04 (0.39)  & 0.04 (0.40)  & 0.04 (0.36) \tabularnewline
~~This is a long description that I can't shrink 201 & 0.04 (0.43)  & 0.05 (0.31)  & 0.08 (0.14)  & 0.05 (0.36)  & 0.07 (0.17)  & 0.06 (0.33) \tabularnewline
~~This is a long description that I can't shrink 201 & 0.10{*} (0.06)  & 0.09{*} (0.08)  & 0.05 (0.37)  & 0.08 (0.14)  & 0.06 (0.25)  & 0.06 (0.21) \tabularnewline
\emph{Controlling variables: } &  &  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
~~This is a long description that I can't shrink 201 &  &  &  & 0.11{*} (0.00)  & 0.10{*} (0.00)  & 0.09{*} (0.01) \tabularnewline
~~This is a long description that I can't shrink 201 &  &  &  & -0.02{*} (0.00)  & -0.02{*} (0.02)  & -0.01{*} (0.03) \tabularnewline
~~This is a long description that I can't shrink 201 &  &  &  & 0.02 (0.41)  & 0.02 (0.51)  & 0.01 (0.62) \tabularnewline
~~This is a long description that I can't shrink 201 &  &  &  & 0.14{*} (0.01)  & 0.15{*} (0.01)  & 0.16{*} (0.01) \tabularnewline
~~This is a long description that I can't shrink 201 &  &  &  & 0.04 (0.30)  & 0.03 (0.49)  & 0.03 (0.48) \tabularnewline
Constant  & 0.80{*} (0.00)  & 0.80{*} (0.00)  & 0.84{*} (0.00)  & 0.75{*} (0.00)  & 0.75{*} (0.00)  & 0.77{*} (0.00) \tabularnewline
Pearson good-of-fitness & 232.03 (1.00) & 213.50 (1.00) & 208.73 (1.00) & 217.32 (1.00) & 200.96 (1.00) & 197.79 (1.00)\tabularnewline
Overdispersion parameter (alpha) & 0.00 (1.00) & 0.00 (1.00) & 0.00 (1.00) & 0.00 (1.00) & 0.00 (1.00) & 0.00 (1.00)\tabularnewline
Observations  & 352  & 324  & 322  & 350  & 323  & 321 \tabularnewline
\midrule 
\multicolumn{7}{c}{ {*} Coefficient significant at least at the 10\% level of significance.
}\tabularnewline
\end{longtable}

  \end{landscape} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: What is the reason for the fifth and six data columns being of a different type (and wider) than the first four data columns?

Comment: Hi @Mico Thank you very much for your answer below. I am still trying to convert the Latex code back to Lyx so couldn't mark yours as answered. Yes, this question bothers me too. I don't know what makes the gap just strangely different. Looking at the Latex code, I couldn't find why? Any suggestions?

Comment: Ohhh! I found why now. When I unset the width of column 5 and 6 (2.25 and 2.24cm) then the table looks nicer and natural now. I was trying to shrink the columns so I preset the widths. That causes problem. Once I unset it, it is okay. Thanks a lot @Mico

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The amount of intercolumn whitespace is set by the parameter `\tabcolsep`. Its default value in the `mwbk` document class is `6pt`. You may find that setting its value to `3pt` generates a table that's more to your taste.

[image]

```
\documentclass[oneside,english]{mwbk}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{eulervm}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,hmargin=1in}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}

%%\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
\newcommand{\noun}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
%% Because html converters don't know tabularnewline
\providecommand{\tabularnewline}{\\}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[format=hang]{caption}

\AtBeginDocument{
  \def\labelitemi{\(\star\)}
  \def\labelitemii{\(\bullet\)}
}

%%\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
  \begin{landscape} 
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}  % default value is "6pt"
\begin{longtable}{@{}lcccc>{\centering}p{2.25cm}>{\centering}p{2.24cm}@{}}
\caption{\textbf{\noun{This is my tables. }}}
\tabularnewline
\midrule
\multirow{2}{*}{\noun{Variables}} & \multicolumn{6}{c}{\noun{Name of dependent variables}}\tabularnewline
\cmidrule{2-7} 
 & (1)  & (2)  & (3)  & (4)  & (5)  & (6) \tabularnewline
\midrule
\emph{Measures of incentives} &  &  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
~~This is a long description that I can't shrink 201 & 0.10{*} (0.04)  &  &  & 0.07 (0.17)  &  & \tabularnewline
~~This is a long description that I can't shrink 201 &  & 0.00 (0.59)  &  &  & 0.00 (0.63)  & \tabularnewline
~~This is a long description that I can't shrink 2012 &  &  & 0.00 (0.11)  &  &  & 0.00 (0.20) \tabularnewline
~~This is a long description that I can't shrink 201 &  &  & 0.00 (0.92)  &  &  & 0.00 (0.85) \tabularnewline
~~This is a long description that I can't shrink 201 &  &  & 0.00 (0.60)  &  &  & 0.00 (0.45) \tabularnewline
\emph{Measures of private benefits} &  &  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
~~This is a long description that I can't shrink 201 & 0.28{*} (0.00)  & 0.24{*} (0.00)  & 0.23{*} (0.00)  & 0.29{*} (0.00)  & 0.25{*} (0.00)  & 0.25{*} (0.00) \tabularnewline
~~This is a long description that I can't shrink 201 & 0.34{*} (0.00)  & 0.35{*} (0.01)  & 0.37{*} (0.01)  & 0.36{*} (0.00)  & 0.40{*} (0.00)  & 0.41{*} (0.00) \tabularnewline
~~This is a long description that I can't shrink 201 & 0.09 (0.11)  & 0.14{*} (0.01)  & 0.12{*} (0.03)  & 0.08 (0.18)  & 0.13{*} (0.03)  & 0.11{*} (0.04) \tabularnewline
~~This is a long description that I can't shrink 201 & 0.14{*} (0.09)  & 0.15{*} (0.06)  & 0.15{*} (0.07)  & 0.13 (0.12)  & 0.15{*} (0.07)  & 0.14{*} (0.08) \tabularnewline
~~This is a long description that I can't shrink 201 & 0.00 (0.46)  & 0.00 (0.65)  & 0.00 (0.81)  & 0.00 (0.84)  & -0.00 (0.86)  & -0.00 (0.78) \tabularnewline
~~This is a long description that I can't shrink 201 & 0.01 (0.88)  & -0.10 (0.22)  & -0.12 (0.16)  & -0.01 (0.95)  & -0.12 (0.16)  & -0.13 (0.13) \tabularnewline
~~This is a long description that I can't shrink 201 & 0.23{*} (0.07)  & 0.33{*} (0.04)  & 0.34{*} (0.04)  & 0.17 (0.15)  & 0.29{*} (0.06)  & 0.29{*} (0.06) \tabularnewline
~~This is a long description that I can't shrink 201 & 0.03 (0.53)  & 0.04 (0.52)  & 0.02 (0.73)  & 0.02 (0.76)  & 0.00 (0.98)  & -0.01 (0.85) \tabularnewline
~~This is a long description that I can't shrink 201 & 0.09 (0.29)  & 0.08 (0.39)  & 0.07 (0.45)  & 0.06 (0.49)  & 0.03 (0.71)  & 0.03 (0.74) \tabularnewline
~~This is a long description that I can't shrink 201 & 0.09 (0.18)  & 0.10 (0.19)  & 0.06 (0.38)  & 0.02 (0.75)  & 0.03 (0.68)  & 0.00 (0.96) \tabularnewline
~~This is a long description that I can't shrink 201 & 0.09 (0.14)  & 0.12{*} (0.05)  & 0.10{*} (0.10)  & 0.07 (0.28)  & 0.07 (0.23)  & 0.06 (0.30) \tabularnewline
~~This is a long description that I can't shrink 201 & 0.06 (0.20)  & 0.07 (0.16)  & 0.06 (0.24)  & 0.04 (0.39)  & 0.04 (0.40)  & 0.04 (0.36) \tabularnewline
~~This is a long description that I can't shrink 201 & 0.04 (0.43)  & 0.05 (0.31)  & 0.08 (0.14)  & 0.05 (0.36)  & 0.07 (0.17)  & 0.06 (0.33) \tabularnewline
~~This is a long description that I can't shrink 201 & 0.10{*} (0.06)  & 0.09{*} (0.08)  & 0.05 (0.37)  & 0.08 (0.14)  & 0.06 (0.25)  & 0.06 (0.21) \tabularnewline
\emph{Controlling variables: } &  &  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
~~This is a long description that I can't shrink 201 &  &  &  & 0.11{*} (0.00)  & 0.10{*} (0.00)  & 0.09{*} (0.01) \tabularnewline
~~This is a long description that I can't shrink 201 &  &  &  & -0.02{*} (0.00)  & -0.02{*} (0.02)  & -0.01{*} (0.03) \tabularnewline
~~This is a long description that I can't shrink 201 &  &  &  & 0.02 (0.41)  & 0.02 (0.51)  & 0.01 (0.62) \tabularnewline
~~This is a long description that I can't shrink 201 &  &  &  & 0.14{*} (0.01)  & 0.15{*} (0.01)  & 0.16{*} (0.01) \tabularnewline
~~This is a long description that I can't shrink 201 &  &  &  & 0.04 (0.30)  & 0.03 (0.49)  & 0.03 (0.48) \tabularnewline
Constant  & 0.80{*} (0.00)  & 0.80{*} (0.00)  & 0.84{*} (0.00)  & 0.75{*} (0.00)  & 0.75{*} (0.00)  & 0.77{*} (0.00) \tabularnewline
Pearson good-of-fitness & 232.03 (1.00) & 213.50 (1.00) & 208.73 (1.00) & 217.32 (1.00) & 200.96 (1.00) & 197.79 (1.00)\tabularnewline
Overdispersion parameter (alpha) & 0.00 (1.00) & 0.00 (1.00) & 0.00 (1.00) & 0.00 (1.00) & 0.00 (1.00) & 0.00 (1.00)\tabularnewline
Observations  & 352  & 324  & 322  & 350  & 323  & 321 \tabularnewline
\midrule 
\multicolumn{7}{c}{ {*} Coefficient significant at least at the 10\% level of significance.
}\tabularnewline
\end{longtable}

  \end{landscape} 
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: As described on p. 7 of the user guide of the `longtable` package, a longtable that occupies the full width of the text block may be obtained by setting the auxiliary parameters `\LTleft` and `\LTright` to `0pt`, setting `\tabcolsep` to `0pt` as well, and inserting the directive `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}` in the descriptor of the `longtable` environment. (This lets LaTeX do the work of determining the amount of intercolumn whitespace needed to make the table fill up the width of the textblock.)

With these adjustments made, and with the column type of the final two columns set to `c` (to match the look of the other four data columns) it is indeed possible to make the table fit inside the text block:

[image]

```
\documentclass[oneside,english]{mwbk}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{eulervm}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,hmargin=1in}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}

%%\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
\newcommand{\noun}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
%% Because html converters don't know tabularnewline
\providecommand{\tabularnewline}{\\}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[format=hang]{caption}

\AtBeginDocument{
  \def\labelitemi{\(\star\)}
  \def\labelitemii{\(\bullet\)}
}

%%\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape} 
  \setlength\LTleft{0pt}
  \setlength\LTright{0pt}
  \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}  % default value is "6pt"
\begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}l*{6}{c}}
\caption{\textbf{\noun{This is my tables. }}}
\tabularnewline
\midrule
\multirow{2}{*}{\noun{Variables}} & \multicolumn{6}{c}{\noun{Name of dependent variables}}\tabularnewline
\cmidrule{2-7} 
 & (1)  & (2)  & (3)  & (4)  & (5)  & (6) \tabularnewline
\midrule
\emph{Measures of incentives} \tabularnewline
~~This is a long description that I can't shrink 201 & 0.10{*} (0.04)  &  &  & 0.07 (0.17)  &  & \tabularnewline
~~This is a long description that I can't shrink 201 &  & 0.00 (0.59)  &  &  & 0.00 (0.63)  & \tabularnewline
~~This is a long description that I can't shrink 2012 &  &  & 0.00 (0.11)  &  &  & 0.00 (0.20) \tabularnewline
~~This is a long description that I can't shrink 201 &  &  & 0.00 (0.92)  &  &  & 0.00 (0.85) \tabularnewline
~~This is a long description that I can't shrink 201 &  &  & 0.00 (0.60)  &  &  & 0.00 (0.45) \tabularnewline
\emph{Measures of private benefits}  \tabularnewline
~~This is a long description that I can't shrink 201 & 0.28{*} (0.00)  & 0.24{*} (0.00)  & 0.23{*} (0.00)  & 0.29{*} (0.00)  & 0.25{*} (0.00)  & 0.25{*} (0.00) \tabularnewline
~~This is a long description that I can't shrink 201 & 0.34{*} (0.00)  & 0.35{*} (0.01)  & 0.37{*} (0.01)  & 0.36{*} (0.00)  & 0.40{*} (0.00)  & 0.41{*} (0.00) \tabularnewline
~~This is a long description that I can't shrink 201 & 0.09 (0.11)  & 0.14{*} (0.01)  & 0.12{*} (0.03)  & 0.08 (0.18)  & 0.13{*} (0.03)  & 0.11{*} (0.04) \tabularnewline
~~This is a long description that I can't shrink 201 & 0.14{*} (0.09)  & 0.15{*} (0.06)  & 0.15{*} (0.07)  & 0.13 (0.12)  & 0.15{*} (0.07)  & 0.14{*} (0.08) \tabularnewline
~~This is a long description that I can't shrink 201 & 0.00 (0.46)  & 0.00 (0.65)  & 0.00 (0.81)  & 0.00 (0.84)  & -0.00 (0.86)  & -0.00 (0.78) \tabularnewline
~~This is a long description that I can't shrink 201 & 0.01 (0.88)  & -0.10 (0.22)  & -0.12 (0.16)  & -0.01 (0.95)  & -0.12 (0.16)  & -0.13 (0.13) \tabularnewline
~~This is a long description that I can't shrink 201 & 0.23{*} (0.07)  & 0.33{*} (0.04)  & 0.34{*} (0.04)  & 0.17 (0.15)  & 0.29{*} (0.06)  & 0.29{*} (0.06) \tabularnewline
~~This is a long description that I can't shrink 201 & 0.03 (0.53)  & 0.04 (0.52)  & 0.02 (0.73)  & 0.02 (0.76)  & 0.00 (0.98)  & -0.01 (0.85) \tabularnewline
~~This is a long description that I can't shrink 201 & 0.09 (0.29)  & 0.08 (0.39)  & 0.07 (0.45)  & 0.06 (0.49)  & 0.03 (0.71)  & 0.03 (0.74) \tabularnewline
~~This is a long description that I can't shrink 201 & 0.09 (0.18)  & 0.10 (0.19)  & 0.06 (0.38)  & 0.02 (0.75)  & 0.03 (0.68)  & 0.00 (0.96) \tabularnewline
~~This is a long description that I can't shrink 201 & 0.09 (0.14)  & 0.12{*} (0.05)  & 0.10{*} (0.10)  & 0.07 (0.28)  & 0.07 (0.23)  & 0.06 (0.30) \tabularnewline
~~This is a long description that I can't shrink 201 & 0.06 (0.20)  & 0.07 (0.16)  & 0.06 (0.24)  & 0.04 (0.39)  & 0.04 (0.40)  & 0.04 (0.36) \tabularnewline
~~This is a long description that I can't shrink 201 & 0.04 (0.43)  & 0.05 (0.31)  & 0.08 (0.14)  & 0.05 (0.36)  & 0.07 (0.17)  & 0.06 (0.33) \tabularnewline
~~This is a long description that I can't shrink 201 & 0.10{*} (0.06)  & 0.09{*} (0.08)  & 0.05 (0.37)  & 0.08 (0.14)  & 0.06 (0.25)  & 0.06 (0.21) \tabularnewline
\emph{Controlling variables: }  \tabularnewline
~~This is a long description that I can't shrink 201 &  &  &  & 0.11{*} (0.00)  & 0.10{*} (0.00)  & 0.09{*} (0.01) \tabularnewline
~~This is a long description that I can't shrink 201 &  &  &  & -0.02{*} (0.00)  & -0.02{*} (0.02)  & -0.01{*} (0.03) \tabularnewline
~~This is a long description that I can't shrink 201 &  &  &  & 0.02 (0.41)  & 0.02 (0.51)  & 0.01 (0.62) \tabularnewline
~~This is a long description that I can't shrink 201 &  &  &  & 0.14{*} (0.01)  & 0.15{*} (0.01)  & 0.16{*} (0.01) \tabularnewline
~~This is a long description that I can't shrink 201 &  &  &  & 0.04 (0.30)  & 0.03 (0.49)  & 0.03 (0.48) \tabularnewline
Constant  & 0.80{*} (0.00)  & 0.80{*} (0.00)  & 0.84{*} (0.00)  & 0.75{*} (0.00)  & 0.75{*} (0.00)  & 0.77{*} (0.00) \tabularnewline
Pearson good-of-fitness & 232.03 (1.00) & 213.50 (1.00) & 208.73 (1.00) & 217.32 (1.00) & 200.96 (1.00) & 197.79 (1.00)\tabularnewline
Overdispersion parameter (alpha) & 0.00 (1.00) & 0.00 (1.00) & 0.00 (1.00) & 0.00 (1.00) & 0.00 (1.00) & 0.00 (1.00)\tabularnewline
Observations  & 352  & 324  & 322  & 350  & 323  & 321 \tabularnewline
\midrule 
\multicolumn{7}{c}{ {*} Coefficient significant at least at the 10\% level of significance.
}\tabularnewline
\end{longtable}

  \end{landscape} 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I'd think of doing this is with @{}. Using @{} you can  make columns use zero, custom or even negative space (i.e., columns overlap).

On purpose I modified your table to contain huge space between some columns, zero space between others, and negative space (making columns overlap). Should you choose this solution, I am sure you will fine-tune it yourself.

```
\documentclass[oneside,english]{mwbk}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
\newcommand{\noun}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
%% Because html converters don't know tabularnewline
\providecommand{\tabularnewline}{\\}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[format=hang]{caption}
\makeatother
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape} 
\begin{longtable}{@{}l@{~~~~~~~~~~~~~}c@{}c@{\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!}c@{}c>{\centering}p{2.25cm}>{\centering}p{2.24cm}}
\caption{\textbf{\noun{This is my tables. }}}
\tabularnewline
\midrule
\multirow{2}{*}{\noun{Variables}} & \multicolumn{6}{c}{\noun{Name of dependent variables}}\tabularnewline
\cmidrule{2-7} 
& (1)  & (2)  & (3)  & (4)  & (5)  & (6) \tabularnewline
\midrule
\emph{Measures of incentives} &  &  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
~~This is a long description that I can't shrink 201 & 0.10{*} (0.04)  &  &  & 0.07 (0.17)  &  & \tabularnewline
~~This is a long description that I can't shrink 201 &  & 0.00 (0.59)  &  &  & 0.00 (0.63)  & \tabularnewline
~~This is a long description that I can't shrink 2012 &  &  & 0.00 (0.11)  &  &  & 0.00 (0.20) \tabularnewline
~~This is a long description that I can't shrink 201 &  &  & 0.00 (0.92)  &  &  & 0.00 (0.85) \tabularnewline
~~This is a long description that I can't shrink 201 &  &  & 0.00 (0.60)  &  &  & 0.00 (0.45) \tabularnewline
\emph{Measures of private benefits} &  &  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
~~This is a long description that I can't shrink 201 & 0.28{*} (0.00)  & 0.24{*} (0.00)  & 0.23{*} (0.00)  & 0.29{*} (0.00)  & 0.25{*} (0.00)  & 0.25{*} (0.00) \tabularnewline
\tabularnewline
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape} [![enter image description here][1]][1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that this necessarily requires a lot of disconnected fiddling where other solutions may be more robust.

Comment: I completely agree, but this may be viewed as an advantage if you have a few exceptionally large tables, but would otherwise want to keep more relaxed column space defaults for the rest of your book

Comment: Even then, you should be making the 'global' change local to a group :) the `@{}` construct is useful for ad-hoc changes.

Comment: Thank @TodorMilev This works too with my table. But I found Mico's answer easier to implement, so I marked Mico's as an accepted answer. But thanks very much for this. I learn another thing too. Will consider this when I have a very large table.